# Asterisk Chan_dongle .call file outbound call without SIP

Tags: asterisk

I have been trying to acheive automatic outbound calling via asterisk .call file using chan_dongle but i have failed to sucessed. I have tried different articles and posted questions over 5 days. I am aiming to acheive this using the simplist method which i think its .call file with minuium configs.
I would like to acheive this without any sip clients connected or any physical phone, just only ASTERISK SERVER Running with Huawei Dongle fully configured and working.

The short version: 
1. Asterisk chan_dongle is setup already and functioning well. (Done)
2. My scrip will gerenate .call file and place it in /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing via cron job.(DONE)
3. I would like to be able to make outgoing call via chan_dongle to another telephony system, wait 5 second and then send certain DTMFs.

my .call file looks like this:

```
Channel: Dongle/dongle0/077XXXXXXXX
MaxRetries: 180
RetryTime: 5
;#### If the call answers, connect it here:
Context: 1
Extension: 1
Priority: 1
```

in my extentions.conf i have :

```
[1]
exten => 1,1,Answer()
exten => 1,n,Wait(5)
exten => 1,n,SendDTMF(wwwwww556111wwww1)
exten => 1,n,Hangup
```

The call goes sucessfully but disconnect immediately after one second. (Drop) chan_dongle report on asterisk counsel:

```
-- Attempting call on Dongle/dongle0/077XXXXXXX for 1@1:1 (Retry 1)
    -- Called dongle0/07724243434
    -- Dongle/dongle0-0100000000 is making progress
    -- Dongle/dongle0-0100000000 answered
[Feb  7 09:44:06] WARNING[951][C-00000001]: pbx.c:4501 __ast_pbx_run: Channel 'Dongle/dongle0-0100000000' sent to invalid extension but no invalid handler: context,exten,priority=1,1,1
[Feb  7 09:44:06] NOTICE[951][C-00000001]: pbx_spool.c:463 attempt_thread: Call completed to Dongle/dongle0/077XXXXXX
```

What i am doing wrong here? how should i acheive this simple call? any help appericated.

PS: I have read somewhere about using Application and Originate commands, but i would like to keep this simple as possible via .call file using dail plan.

Thank alot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have no extension 1,1,1. Try reload asterisk and debug why your context not included in dialplan.

```
asterisk -rx "dialplan show 1"
```

Comment: Yes i do not have sip client or phone connected to asterisk. I dont want that, I just need the asterisk server to dail out alone with the .call file and execute the dail plan, is it possibe?

Comment: Extension = extension in dialplan. Your problem have no any relation to SIP at all, forget about SIP.

Comment: You are right, this what i get on running "asterisk -rx "dialplan show 1"" : Command 'dialplan show 1' failed. but i dont know the problem in my extentions.conf i have: [general]
[1]
exten => 1,1,Answer()
exten => 1,n,Wait(5)
exten => 1,n,SendDTMF(wwwwww87237621wwww1)
exten => 1,n,Hangup

Comment: Thanks a lot the problem has been solved, You were right something was wrong with extensions.conf , i have delete the file, nano new one copy dailplan now everything is working fine!. thanks for saving me.